# deserializing json with arrays

Tags: json, jackson

im using jackson to deserialize some Json.  I am reading through a large json document and pulling out blocks and telling jackson to take that block and deserialize it to an object that I created (Actually several objects as there are nested arrays) in java to match the json.

The code im using to deserialize is

```
fooObject newFoo = mapper.readValue(newNode,fooObject.class);
```

The problem is there is a value in the block that is sometimes a hash such as

```
addWidgetStrategy={"get":2,"spend":6,"textLabel":"bikes"}
```

and sometimes an array

```
addWidgetStrategy=[{"get":1.5,"spend":3,"textLabel":"thursday"},{"get":3,"spend":5,"textLabel":"tuesday"}]
```

So in fooObject I need to deal with addWidgetStrategy which has its own object.  If in fooObject I put

```
public addWidgetStrategy addWidgetStrategy;
```

The above works until it tried to deserialize an array

If I put

```
public List<addWidgetStrategy>  addWidgetStrategy;
```

it works just for arrays and blows up when its just a single hash

How can I parse that same Json element addWidgetStrategy regardless if its an array or a single hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arrays it should be:

```
   fooObject[] newFoo = mapper.readValue(newNode,fooObject[].class);
```

You can read it like this:

```
   JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
   if (jsonNode.isArray()) {
       fooObject[] newFoo = mapper.readValue(jsonNode,fooObject[].class);
       ...
   } else {
       fooObject newFoo = mapper.readValue(jsonNode,fooObject.class);  
       ....
   }
```